# Should a PhD student use his academic affiliation for his publications which are not related to his thesis?

Tags: publications, ethics, affiliation

If a PhD student is working on a research project which is neither related to his thesis topic, nor supported by the university in which he is studying or a faculty member; Does he have the right to use his academic affiliation and contact email?

There are two points here,

- If the student is using the university facilities, he may acknowledge that support in the Acknowledgement section of his paper not by using the university affiliation.
- The university in which the student is studying in doesn't necessarily want to be associated with whatever research he does in his free hours.

P.S.: Does this consideration apply to the researchers who work in a research institute or company?

Comment: The more general version of this question has been [asked and answered](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3446/what-is-the-criterion-to-include-an-institution-as-affiliation-in-an-author-li). I believe this may be a duplicate.

Comment: To comment on your PS. A researcher in a company would almost certainly not be permitted to use the company name as affiliation for research that is not endorsed by the company.

Comment: The question is "what are criterion for including affiliation," and the accepted answer detailed when you *must* and when you *may* include an affiliation.

Comment: Probably a closer duplicate: [Rules for affiliation for student doing unpaid research in his/her free time?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/890/rules-for-affiliation-for-student-doing-unpaid-research-in-his-her-free-time) (which is *not* only about undergraduate students)

Comment: I won't post this as an answer because it's not directly related to your question, but your University policy and/or your work contract may also restrict the work you are doing in addition to what you are paid for by your employer. Specifically, in your case, doing research for a collaboration or on your own could fall into the "additional work" category if it's not directly related to your Ph.D., and you should need your advisor/University agreement anyway.

Comment: If this is legitimate research, and you used university resources of any kind, couldn't the university actually ***require*** you to use their affiliation. They can certainly require you to give them a share in any patent rights.

Comment: Mostly for interest, but may be relevant to the question: how *different* are your main field and the side project in question? Is it more like field A in computer science and field B in CS - or rather like CS and behavioral biology?

Comment: @xLeitix I am not sure about other majors, but in civil engineering there are broad research fields available and researchers sometimes work on two or three research fields. For instance, one may work on computational mechanics as his main research field and work on construction materials properties as his second research field (which does not consume that much energy and time and is so interesting for him). This way researchers in civil engineering usually work on two or three research fields.

Comment: If the student has a graduate assistantship, then it would be normal for the student to use the sponsoring university as her affiliation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Yes.

The affiliation serves two purposes: acknowledgement and identification.

Even if it is not part of your thesis research, if you are receiving resources *of any kind* from your institution, you should list them as your affiliation.  These resources include money (whether directly related to your research or not), computing equipment, internet access, printer access, electricity, phones, faculty and student colleagues (whether coauthors or not), library access (either physical or electronic), whiteboards, local coffee shops/bars, and the general intellectual atmosphere that encourages you to do research in the first place. You can afford to be generous.

Also, the affiliation helps identify you as an author, especially if you have a common name, or you publish other papers with the same affiliation.

Comment: My PhD advisor, most of my former PhD students, and I all published papers as students without any faculty member's contribution.  This is not only completely, utterly, absolutely normal and accepted practice in my field, but _strongly encouraged_ practice, at every one of the 11 institutions (7 in the US, 4 in Europe) where I have been affiliated, as a student, postdoc, faculty, or sabbatical visitor. **Researchers should be allowed to submit their research for publication without interference from their university. Whether they are faculty, students, or janitors is utterly irrelevant.**

Answer (score 7):

First step: Ask your (1) advisor or (2) the department head or (3) both. Since you are not faculty, you may have to get permission to use the departmental affiliation for something that is outside your project. As long as this involves ethical and legitimate research I am sure it is not a problem. The department or university may have guidelines for publishing ethics which you may want to check as well. So, although there may not even be a problem, it is better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: _you may have to get permission_ — What??

Comment: @JeffE In some places there is such law (e.g. in mine). Usually it is a formality (I guess to protect themselves against people publishing substandard things).

Comment: I must say that I am learning from these answers how shabbily graduate students are treated in some parts of the world.  Also the protection from substandard work ought to be the refereeing process, not some university regulations!  This makes me sad...

Answer (score 0):

It can just be published as "unsponsored research".  If they value their relationships highly though, they should dialog with their professors.

Comment: If the student is being paid by the university (e.g. as a graduate assistant or part of a research group), then it can't really be called "unsponsored". (I haven't voted on this answer.)

Comment: The OP says it is not sponsored by the university, so is not a GA or part of a university research group.

Comment: The OP does say he is studying at a university; I think the question is somewhat ambiguous about whether the OP is being paid to be in a research group.

Comment: One could be doing research outside of work hours, then the university would not be sponsoring that research.

Comment: @Davidmh: that may depend on the field somewhat, but in my field of math it would be bizarre to try to separate "work hours" from other hours - research happens on its own schedule. Perhaps a laboratory scientist could separate time in the lab from time at home, but then how would they do research at home?

Comment: @OswaldVeblen:   If one is doing work that was not suggested by a professor, is not paid by the institution, then one is doing one's own private research, which at some time may be given under the umbrella of the institution.

Comment: @Mark J: yes, of course - assuming that the OP is not being paid *at all* by the institution. The question is somewhat ambiguous about whether the OP is being paid at all by the university.

Comment: @OswaldVeblen I am required to work (and paid for) 39 h a week. Even on a flexible schedule, anything I do outside these hours is not paid by the university.

Comment: @Davidmh As soon as you once download a paper from a paid website or use a paid search service, you are sponsored by the university.

Comment: @tohecz IANAL, but it could be argued that the paper was downloaded for my actual paid research, and I reused that knowledge. For what happened IRL, I know that in industry there have been judicial sentences in both directions, so it is certanly a shady area.

Comment: @Davidmh: that's not how academic research works; faculty don't separate "paid" research and "unpaid" research - e.g. summer research, even if "unpaid", is still affiliated with the institution. (Also, the typical faculty workload according to many studies is about 55 hours per week, much more than 39.) This is one reason that the premise underlying the OP's question is hard to understand - assuming you have only one job, and the job is at a university, that university is normally the affiliation for all your academic work.

Comment: @tohecx:  No, as a student they are already in the University system.  Using the services which are part of being a student, does not make them "sponsored".

Comment: @MarkJ Affiliation has nothing to do with "sponsorship".

Answer (score -3):

Sorry to revive old post, but here's one more perspective - consider not some abstract "right" of the student, but rather the political and practical aspect for somebody building a career. For argument's sake, OP, let's assume your paper was on a totally unrelated subject, using no university resources, i.e.,  typed up at home on a personally owned laptop. Even so, think about how your advisor will react when he is surprised to learn that you have been spending time and energy working on this significant outside project and didn't even tell him. PhD students in sciences receive a full stipend, and that is supposed to sponsor *ALL* your academic energy (regardless of day/night). After all, some of us do our best work at night and at home. The time it would take to conduct independent research and publish is easily like a moonlighting job, and this is usually frowned upon or explicitly forbidden. It is a distraction from your dissertation, and will likely slow down the research of your advisor who is paying your stipend. Finally and most importantly, the advisor has powerful influence over your professional future. When that advisor is writing the all-important recommendation letter, you want him to say you are dedicated, focused, and hard working, not that you are an irresponsible dilettante / rogue player. I know this may sound harsh, but it is the reality of the world. (I'm a full professor in the sciences at a top 10 US university, and I have advised 12 PhD students over 20 years.)

Comment: I'm afraid that you sound like a terrible person to have as an advisor.

Comment: _think about how your advisor will react_ — With proud congratulations.  (I am also a full professor in the sciences at a top 10 university, and I have advised 9 PhD students over 17 years.)

Comment: I admire JeffE's principles, and I know I come across as harsh. I value my mentorship relationships greatly, it is in fact the main reason I'm in academia, and it is the only reason I posted the above opinion - for the protection of the student. The PhD program isn't a continuation of undergrad, when taking "electives" and extracurriculars were encouraged. IMHO when one reaches the PhD level, it is time to focus and devote all academic energy to that degree. At the least, before conducting a major side project, run it by your advisor to get his blessings. After all, you do value his advice?