# What order should I list author affiliations on a conference poster?

Tags: conference, authorship, affiliation, poster

First and foremost, as the title suggests, in what sort of order should I put author affiliations on the poster? Alphabetical? First author's affiliation, then alphabetical, or some other way (and do excuse me if a similar question has been asked and answered)?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia SE! You may want to consider asking your second question about your affiliation in a separate post.

Comment: I am taking the liberty of removing your second question, about affiliations, as otherwise your question is in danger of being put on hold.  I believe that you may find the answer your are looking for in [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3446/22733).  If not, please ask your question about affiliations as a new question.  If you disagree with what I've done, feel free to roll-back the edit.

Comment: No problem. I was asking mainly because my own university isn't providing any funding for this while the university I'm doing the fellowship/internship at is paying for everything (housing, food, travel, activities, etc. plus a modest stipend)

Comment: I'm not certain that the linked question above answers the 2nd question which was edited out of the post.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, affiliations are listed in the same order as order of authors.
Listing them on a poster should be no different than listing them on a paper or in any other form of scientific communication.

Thus, for example, if you have the following set of authors:

> Smith, affiliated with Ivy University
>
> Chou, affiliated with Arrwun Tech
>
> Patel, affiliated with Ivy University
>
> Garcia, affiliated with McName Institute

Then you would typically list them as something like the following (adjusted for your desired format):

> Smith, Chou, Patel, and Garcia
>
> Smith and Patel are at Ivy University, Chou is at Arrwun Tech, Garcia is at McName Institute.

As for when authors have multiple affiliations: for any given author, affiliations should be listed in descending order of importance (as judged by the author).  Typically there is a clear "primary" affiliation which comes first, and the order of any others after it matters much less.  The order of the overall set across all authors is determined just the same way as when there are single affiliations, by listing all in order and combining duplicates.